# JavaScript switching tabs & windows in same browser

Tags: javascript, browser, userscripts

First of all I need to determine which window or tab is actually opened in browser at the moment. I need it's name or create it by specifying unique value which I'm able to find for each one of them.

Then I need to switch between these tabs and windows. Are there any commands to do so?

1. I Need to copy some string value.
2. Need to change tab.
3. Click a button.
4. New window appears.
5. Click a button.
6. Paste this text.
7. Click a button.
8. Close this window.
9. Get back to 1st tab I was on.

Those are steps I want to automate.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: From code within a page? From an extension? If so, which kind (as the answer will vary from browser to browser)?

Comment: I'm on google chrome with tampermonkey extension, creating script that is manipulating code on the web. This script needs to move between them. I hope I've answered your question cause I dont really get it.

Comment: Try telling us *exactly* what you do manually that you want to automate.  **List every step, and with enough detail that we can duplicate the process.**  Then, and only then, can we help you automate it.

Comment: okay, so I've edited my question and added all steps I need to go throught. Thank you for your comments guys.

Comment: For all that, you really should use something like *iMacros*.

Comment: Also, you did not provide the detail we need to replicate.  Provide an MCVE.